# Error importing binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy from keras backend: Cannot import name

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras import layers
      2 import keras.backend as backend
      3 import tensorflow as tf

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py:13, in <module>
     10 import sys as _sys
     12 from keras import __version__
---> 13 from keras.api._v2.keras import __internal__
     14 from keras.api._v2.keras import activations
     15 from keras.api._v2.keras import applications

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\__init__.py:8, in <module>
      3 """Public API for tf. namespace.
      4 """
      6 import sys as _sys
----> 8 from keras.api import keras
      9 from tensorflow.python.util import module_wrapper as _module_wrapper
     11 if not isinstance(_sys.modules[__name__], _module_wrapper.TFModuleWrapper):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\keras\__init__.py:16, in <module>
     14 from keras.api.keras import activations
     15 from keras.api.keras import applications
---> 16 from keras.api.keras import backend
     17 from keras.api.keras import callbacks
     18 from keras.api.keras import constraints

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\api\keras\backend\__init__.py:24, in <module>
     22 from keras.backend import binary_crossentropy
     23 from keras.backend import binary_focal_crossentropy
---> 24 from keras.backend import binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy
     25 from keras.backend import cast
     26 from keras.backend import cast_to_floatx

ImportError: cannot import name 'binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy' from 'keras.backend' (D:\Users\DGong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py)
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting an import error here. I've uninstalled and reinstalled `tensorflow` and `keras` many times, as well as used both pip and pip3. I checked the file and nothing seems to be different between the way `binary_focal_crossentropy` and `binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy` is exported. But the former seems to import without error.

Comment: Can you give the full stack? What are you importing that has `binary_focal_crossentropy`, I've never seen these functions.

Comment: @MZ Just edited with the full stack!

Answer (score 0):

You can import and use `tf.keras.metrics.binary_focal_crossentropy` by importing the metrics library below.

Also, Instead of `pip` installing each package(`TensorFlow, Keras`) separately, the recommended approach is to install `Keras` as part of the `TensorFlow` installation. When you install `TensorFlow >2.0`,  Keras will be automatically installed, as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import binary_focal_crossentropy
```

You can check more about [binary_focal_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/binary_focal_crossentropy) in the given link.

Comment: your line .... from tensorflow.keras import layers ....... gives me the same error binary_focal_crossentropy cant be imported from keras backend.  
is this stilll correct? im using new versions