# cannot import name 'binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy' from 'keras.backend'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

im trying to import categorical_dqn

when i try the following

```
from tf_agents.agents.categorical_dqn import categorical_dqn_agent
```

i get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py)
```

the advice i find around the internet [Error importing binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy from keras backend: Cannot import name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957098/error-importing-binary-weighted-focal-crossentropy-from-keras-backend-cannot-im) is to try importing this stuff first

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import binary_focal_crossentropy
```

i end up with the exact same error caused by the second line of this suggestion however.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'binary_weighted_focal_crossentropy' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py)
```

####### bonus info ########

im running all this on anaconda

tensorflow version = 2.9.2

tf agents version = 0.5.0

keras version = 2.9.0

im trying to follow this tutorial  = https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/9_c51_tutorial.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `tf_agents` a few months ago. Doing this fixed it for me:

```
pip install tf-agents[reverb]
```

I have the following packages with their respective versions:

```
keras                         2.9.0
tensorflow                    2.9.2
tf-agents                     0.13.0
```

Comment: can i ask what versions of everything your using?

ive tried that and get 
Requirement already satisfied: tf-agents[reverb] in c:\users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.5.0)
WARNING: tf-agents 0.5.0 does not provide the extra 'reverb'

and it doesnt fix anything

Comment: Sure, I've added some more info to my answer. Perhaps you can try upgrading tf-agents version.

Comment: yep, it seems to have been my tf-agents version. 

i still get errors with reverb, but now i dont need reverb. thank you